# Don't Display Photo if Not Found

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, image

I'm developing a browser extension (content script) that scans and highlights certain words on a page, and uses AJAX and PHP to echo back content into a tooltip that appears when a user hover over said words. One thing that gets echoed back from the PHP file is an image, but my problem is that I don't have an image for every keyword - what I want is the PHP to only echo back an image when  one exists at the given URL. As of now, certain words show images, others show the "image not found" icon. What I want is for **no** "image not found" icon if the image doesn't exist.

I have the AJAX send the variable ($data) to the PHP files hosted on my website. Maybe have it check the HTTP header of the url before echoing?

Here is my code:

> $data = $_POST['id'];
>
> echo "http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/" . $data . ".png'>";

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just check it like this?

```
$data = $_POST['id'];
if($data !== "") {
    echo "http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/" . $data . ".png'>";
}

else {
    echo "http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/notFound.png'>";
}
```

EDIT:

Use `file_exists()`:

```
$data = $_POST['id'];
$imagePath = "/path/images/" . $data . ".png";

if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
    echo "http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/" . $data . ".png'>";
}

else {
    echo "http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/notFound.png'>";
}
```

Comment: That's not the problem - $data will always have a value (it's used more than once in the PHP file). For example, $data could be N300035 and an image exists at extension.nicholasrub.in/N300035.png. But, $data could also be N980056, and an image does not exist at extension.nicholasrub.in/N980056.png.

Comment: @NickRubin Pic `extension.nicholasrub.in/N300035.png` is not found for me

Comment: @Max that was just an example, sorry. Here's a working link - http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/N00026171.png.

Comment: file_exists() of $data? file_exists('N300035')?

Comment: @Max wouldn't it need to be the full URL? I don't see how file_exists('N300035') would do anything.

Comment: `if (file_exists('http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/' . $data . '.png')) {
echo "<div id='my-tooltip-2986234'><div><img src='http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/" . $data . ".png'>";
}
else {
echo "<div id='my-tooltip-2986234'><div>";
}`

Comment: @VilleRouhiainen the code works, but it's says the file doesn't exist even if it does, and it's always executing the else section. Maybe because my imagePath is `http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/" . $data . ".png`?

Comment: @VilleRouhiainen I ended up solving it myself by just checking whether the HTTP headers are 404. If they are 404, I don't show the image, if they aren't, I show it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NickRubin Yea you should've changed the imagePath to correct one, example "/headshots" or something like that, depends really where your .php file is run from. But cool that you got your problem solved, maybe post your own solution and mark it correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a file exists using this function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check image what is not exist on your server then use this code:

```
$data = $_POST['id'];
$imagePath = "http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/$data.png";
echo "http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/".(file_get_contents(imagePath) ? $data : 'notFound').".png'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem by checking whether the HTTP headers were 404 or not.

**My Code:**

```
$file = "http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/" . $data . ".png";

$file_headers = @get_headers($file);

if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}

if ($exists == true) {
    echo "<div id='my-tooltip-2986234'><div><img src='http://extension.nicholasrub.in/headshots/" . $data . ".png'>";
}
else {
    echo "<div id='my-tooltip-2986234'><div>";
}
```